# Pandas datetime comparison

Tags: pandas, datetime, comparison

I have the following dataframe:

```
start = ['31/12/2011 01:00','31/12/2011 01:00','31/12/2011 01:00','01/01/2013 08:00','31/12/2012 20:00']  
end =   ['02/01/2013 01:00','02/01/2014 01:00','02/01/2014 01:00','01/01/2013 14:00','01/01/2013 04:00']                                                  
df = pd.DataFrame({'start':start,'end':end})  
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'],format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'],format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
print(df)

          end                 start
0  2013-01-02 01:00:00   2011-12-31 01:00:00
1  2014-01-02 01:00:00   2011-12-31 01:00:00
2  2014-01-02 01:00:00   2011-12-31 01:00:00
3  2013-01-01 14:00:00   2013-01-01 08:00:00
4  2013-01-01 04:00:00   2012-12-31 20:00:00
```

I am tying to compare `df.end` and `df.start` to two given dates, `year_start` and `year_end`:

```
year_start = pd.to_datetime(2013,format='%Y')
year_end = pd.to_datetime(2013+1,format='%Y')
print(year_start)
print(year_end)
2013-01-01 00:00:00
2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

But i can't get my comparison to work (comparison in conditions):

```
conditions = [(df['start'].any()< year_start) and (df['end'].any()> year_end)]
choices = [8760]
df['test'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

I also tried to define `year_end` and `year_start` as follows but it does not work either:

```
year_start = np.datetime64(pd.to_datetime(2013,format='%Y'))
year_end = np.datetime64(pd.to_datetime(2013+1,format='%Y'))
```

Any idea on how I could make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [797]: df[(df['start']< year_start) & (df['end']> year_end)]
Out[797]: 
                  end               start
1 2014-01-02 01:00:00 2011-12-31 01:00:00
2 2014-01-02 01:00:00 2011-12-31 01:00:00
```